# VBS Script - Run series of .batch jobs

Tags: vbscript

Help me run a series of .bat script

they are located like so:

p:\Co-Brand\export.bat
p:\Generic\export.bat
p:\Tri-Brand\export.bat

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way that works, should have tried this first of all.
I am a bit embarrassed that it was this easy actually:

cd P:\Co-Brand\

CALL Export.bat

cd P:\Generic\

CALL Export.bat

cd P:\TriBrand\

CALL Export.bat

cd P:\UBA\

CALL Export.bat

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple shell command do? You can call this from a command prompt:

```
for /R %F in (*.bat) do "%F"
```

or the following from a .bat file:

```
for /R %%F in (*.bat) do call "%%F"
```

Comment: well what I would really like to do is execute a batch script from the end of a .vbs script. I have been having issues trying to run these from cmd prompt and .bat scripts with not finding correct paths. For some reason it seems to use the same path as from where you execute it from rather than from where the actual .bat script is placed. Was hoping that a .vbs script would help, but the way its looking is that it probably wont. Any way to specify path, to use the path where the file is placed?

Answer (score 0):

As originally asked, here is a VBScript solution...

The problem described is probably related to the "Script-Working-Directory".

Try this ...

```
    Dim objShell
    Dim blnWaitOnReturn
    Dim strOriginalCD
    Dim strCmd
    Dim intWindowStyle
    Dim intExitCode

    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 '' if necessary, save the original "Script-Working-Directory"
    strOriginalCD = objShell.CurrentDirectory

    intWindowStyle = 1
    blnWaitOnReturn = True

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Co-Brand\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    intExitCode = objShell.Run(strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn)

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Generic\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    intExitCode = objShell.Run(strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn)

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Tri-Brand\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    intExitCode = objShell.Run(strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn)

 '' if necessary, restore the original "Script-Working-Directory"
    objShell.CurrentDirectory = strOriginalCD
```

Notes:

```
 '' If filename contains spaces make sure to add double-quotes around filename
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K " & Chr(34) & "File name with spaces.bat" & Chr(34)

 '' To run the commands in a "Hidden" window, use:
    intWindowStyle = 0

 '' To run the commands "Minimized", use:
    intWindowStyle = 7
```

More info on "objShell.Run" can be found here: http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

The above examples will cause VBScript to wait for each called ".bat" to complete and return an "ExitCode" before proceeding.

If you don't want VBScript to wait for one ".bat" to complete before proceeding to the next then set blnWaitOnReturn = False, and remove intExitCode like:

```
    ...
    blnWaitOnReturn = False

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Co-Brand\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    objShell.Run strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Generic\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    objShell.Run strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "p:\Tri-Brand\"
    strCmd = "%comspec% /K export.bat"
    objShell.Run strCmd, intWindowStyle, blnWaitOnReturn
    ...
```

If you want the ability to get the "Status" and "ProcessID", and access the standard streams of the executable to read/write to the process's stdout/stderr in real-time while the process executes, then use "objShell.Exec".

More info on "objShell.Exec" can be found here: http://ss64.com/vb/exec.html