# run every batch file in a directory batch script

Tags: batch-file

First off, I would like to thank everyone for the amazing information you provide.

Now, to my issue. I need to write a batch file that will execute every batch file in every directory and subdirectory. I tried this to no avail.

for /R %%f in (*.bat) do call "%%f"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

I'm writing a .bat file, not a .vbs file. Will the same syntax work? Also, I've tried the above code, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Run program in a new window, or execute in the original window?

Comment: Execute in the same window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBS Script - Run series of .batch jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918717/vbs-script-run-series-of-batch-jobs)

Comment: What happened when you ran that command?  If you have the batch file with this `for` command in the same directory, it will run itself and be in an endless loop.  Is that what is happening?

Comment: Nope, it is in a level above all of the other .bat files. It seems to run something quickly, and the cmd window closes before I can see what is printed out. I've tried using the pause command as well.

Comment: Then you need to tell the `for /R` loop which directory to start in. Put the directory name in quotes after the `/R`.

Comment: And run the script directly from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: ******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=265, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******

Comment: I think I'm doing something stupid, the above is the error that I get. It only has to drill down a few levels. It certainly isn't 265 levels.

Comment: Try `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir/s/b "r:\path\*.bat"') do call "%%f"` and be sure not to call this batch file! For example: `.....do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 call "%%f"` Maybe this way you won't need my variant of loop with `dir`.

Comment: as for the path, I just want the .bat file to start its execution from the directory that it is in - wherever I put it.

Comment: And I don't want to specify the path to the batch file - I want it to execute every batch file that is under itself in the subsequent directories.

Comment: Something like this, but I want it to do it recursively, not just for the files in its own folder.                                                                                          for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /B /AD') do (stuffToDo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid self-recursion check the name before executing:

```
for /R %%f in (*.bat) do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 call "%%f"
```

And Nick's variant to set each batch file's working directory to its own directory:

```
for /R %%f in (*.bat) do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 (cd %%~pf & call "%%f")
```

Comment: You guys are so awesome. We are getting closer. That one actually runs, but fails to drill down into the folders beneath itself. I believe the self recursion was a problem, but it still isn't quite functioning yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: Okay, I think I what wOxxOm said works. I just need it to change the working directory to the one that each batch file is in. Each "slave" batch file writes a file for itself to use. Now, that file is getting written to the parent directory, and the "slave" batch file cannot find it. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to change to the "slave" directory.    for /r %%f in (*.bat) do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 (cd %~dp0 & call "%%f")

Comment: for /r %%f in (*.bat) do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 (cd %~dp0 & call "%%f")

Comment: for /r %%f in (*.bat) do if not %%f==%~dpnx0 (cd %%~pf & call "%%f")

Comment: And the website that I found info on this listed below. Thanks SO much for all of your help. You guys are AWESOME!

Comment: wow, you're so fast :-) I'll add your variant if you think my answer is worth accepting.